# Killing vector field with integral orthogonal distribution

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. When is it true that the $(n-1)$-dimensional leaves of a foliation given by a Killing vector field with integral orthogonal distribution are the orbit of a group acting (transitively) by isometries?

Comment: Obviously not true generically. Take a surface with no symmetries, and cross with the real line, with product metric. Translation on the real line is the Killing field.

Comment: Yes. Obviously. Is it true in the case of a homogeneous manifold for example?

Comment: No. Try the hyperbolic plane. In the upper half plane model, horizontal translation is a Killing field, but the vertical lines are not the orbits of any Killing fields, since any nonzero Killing field cannot preserve two vertical lines. The vertical lines are all geodesics, but to preserve the metric on each vertical line, you have to rescale the vertical axis by a constant, and then to preserve the metric, you have to rescale the horizontal axis by the same factor. There is no Killing field everywhere tangent to the vertical lines.

Comment: What examples have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which made me realize the question is poorly stated.

Indeed, as stated, we can conclude that M is locally a direct product L x I where L is orthogonal to X and I is an interval (which fails even when M=R^n and X is a rotation). Locally M = L x I as a manifold with metric g = g_L + f dt, where f is independent of t.  But then to be invariant under a group acting transitively on L, f must be constant, so M = L x I as a Riemannian manifold.

I think I asked for too much: I only want to assume that a single leaf L has a transitive action of a group of isometries.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $M$ is closed. Let $X$ be the killing vector field and $G$ the group of isometries which acts transitively on the distribution transverse to the orbits of $X$. Every element of $g$ preserves the foiation ${\cal F}$ defined by the orbits of $X$ since it is an isometry which preserves the distribution orthogonal to $X$. We deduce that $X$ is a riemannian flow. The adherence of its orbits are diffeomorphic to a torus (Carriere). Moreover, $M$ is a total space of a fibration $p:M\rightarrow B$ where the fibres are the adherence of the leaves of ${\cal F}$. The action of $G$ descents on $B$ and defines on it a transitive action. To summarize:

$M$ is a total space of a fibration over an homogeneous $G$-manifold whose fibres are diffeomorphic to torus $\mathbb{T}^n$.

If you want to have details about riemannian foliations you can read the book of Molino:

Molino Pierre, Riemannian foliations.